# Calculate the height of a triangle

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, triangles

The triangle ABC is a right angle triangle. I'm trying to figure out the distance AC, i.e the height of the triangle.

[image]

My bet is that I could use the uniformity of triangle ABC and CDO to solve the height. Let AC=h and OD=b. That should mean that $$\frac{h-3.5}{h}=\frac{b}{7}=\frac{\sqrt{b^2+(h-3.5)^2}}{\sqrt{7^2+h^2}}$$
However there's a problem. I have to unknown variables so I can't get any further from here. Maybe I can use the fact that I can express b in form of h, such as $$\frac{b}{7}=\frac{h-3.5}{h}=>b=7\frac{h-3.5}{h}$$
I also know that the angle $$\angle AOB=arcsin(\frac{7}{\sqrt{7^2+3.5^2}})=63.43°=>\angle ABO=180°-90°-63.43°=26.57°$$
I feel like if I could figure out the $\angle OBD$, I could calculate the heigh h. However, in order for me to figure out $\angle OBD$, I need to find out DB, which should be $CB-CD$. $$DB=CB-CD=\sqrt{7^2+h^2}-\sqrt{(\frac{7(h-3.5)}{h})^2+(h-3.5)^2 }$$
Therefore the angle $\angle OBD$ could be found from 
$$\frac{sin(\angle OBD)}{\frac{7(h-3.5)}{h}}=\frac{\angle DOB}{DB}==\frac{26.57°}{\sqrt{7^2+h^2}-\sqrt{(\frac{7(h-3.5)}{h})^2+(h-3.5)^2 }}$$
I think I've either done something wrong because they numbers are getting silly now or I'm using the wrong technique.
Does anyone have an idea on how I could calculate the height?

Comment: Is ABC right triangle or isoceles triangle ?

Comment: Those information are not enough and $C$ can be at any height.

Comment: In ABC , the $\angle ABC$ is marked with a 90°-angle box, so ABC is a right angle triangle

Answer (score 0):

It depends what are the know factors. 
Usually when you have parallel lines in a triangle, **Thales** is your friend.

You have $\dfrac{CO}{CA}=\dfrac{OD}{AB}$, which means

$\dfrac{CA-3.5}{CA}=\dfrac{OD}{7}$, or $AC=\dfrac{3.5}{1-\frac{OD}{7}}$

Comment: Yea, that's what I found out aswell except I wrote it as $$OD=\frac{AC-3.5}{AC}$$
Should I be able to solve it from what you wrote?

Comment: @TomRigby The problem is the known and unkown factors. If all you know is what is on your diagram / drawing, you can't find $AC$. $C$ could be at any height. If you have other information, maybe we could.

Comment: @TomRigby By the way, what you wrote is not the same as what I wrote. Look at the formulas in details.

Comment: Oh, ok. I also know that the C is a points outside a cirlce, from C, two lines are tangents to the circle, the points where the lines tangent the circle, I get a chord, which is the bottom of the isosceles triangle and the height from the chord to the circles periphery is 3.5 (AO)

Comment: @TomRigby You should defintely change your diagram or the text accordingly, because this is a critical missing element. A diagram wouldbe better, becasue I have to admit that your wording is not clear to me as to where the circle is.